# Track failure of command on a Salt minion

Tags: salt-stack

I am using salt for last one month. Whenever I run a command say `sudo salt '*' test.ping`, then the master pings all the minions and the response being the list of all the minions which are up and running. Output looks something like:

```
{
"minion_1": true
}
{
"minion_2": true
}
{
"minion_3": true
}
```

In the master's `conf` file, return type is configured to JSON.
But if I execute an incorrect command through salt master say `sudo salt '*' test1.ping`, then the master returns something like this

```
{
"minion_1": "'test1.ping' is not available."
}
{
"minion_2": "'test1.ping' is not available."
}
{
"minion_3": "'test1.ping' is not available."
}
```

In both the outputs displayed above, the command has given a success exit code on the master's shell/terminal. How do we track which minions were not able to execute the commands. I am not interested in what type of error it is, I just need some or the other way to track the minions which failed to execute the command.

The last solution is to write a parser which will read the complete output and decide for itself. Hope that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Reasons to despair

I would not rely on Salt's CLI exit code at the moment (version `2014.7.5`) - [there are still many issues opened](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/18510) to solve this.

### Get valid JSON output

There is [`--static`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/2014.7/ref/cli/salt-call.html#cmdoption-salt-call--out) option which fixes JSON output:

> If using `--out=json`, you will probably want `--static` as well. Without the static option, you will get a JSON string for each minion.

Otherwise the output given by Salt above contains *multiple* objects (one per minion) which is not a valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (JSON requires *single* object, array or value per document) and simple way of loading entire output by a standard JSON parser will fail. It is even mentioned in [documentation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/output/all/salt.output.json_out.html) (as of [`5188d6c`](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/43e69d2842c34cfb49b8997c7c3d5b378b43406a/salt/output/json_out.py#L20)):

> Some JSON parsers can guess when an object ends and a new one begins but many can not.

In addition to that, some Salt options (like `show_jid`) also send strings to STDOUT which mixes it with execution report and invalidates JSON output format. Option `--static` also solves this problem.

### UPDATE: Parser to detect failure in Salt execution

This problem squeezed me so much so I gave quick birth to [this Python script @ 75e42af](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/75e42afb04cbd7d82722c9793c1c9be6637b8bbd/states/bootstrap/bootstrap.dir/modules/utils/check_salt_output.py) with [example how it is used @ b819961d](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/b819961dbb683285329084952f24dab6f30d07c6/states/common/jenkins/configure_jobs_ext/build_bootstrap_package.xml#L57).

NOTE: This won't address output of arbitrary Salt command (including `test.ping` above), but issues related to the output of state execution are covered. There is still a solution to `test.ping` problem above - it can be run from state, then the output can be analysed by the script. See how to call an execution module from within a state or `*.sls` file [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20788572/441652).

*Features* (details in the code itself):

- Handle output from both `highstate` and `orchestrate` runners.
- Handle output of multiple minions and any number of commands.
- Report summary "? of N" and overall result.
- Standalone file usable as script and module.

The only limitation is that it requires JSON output (Salt option `--out json`) simply because it is easy to fix the discussed issues before feeding it to parser.

Answer (score 0):

The above parser will only work for test.ping command.
If multiple commands have to be executed we will have to write a more robust parser.

Comment: I updated the answer to make it robust enough. @Inder Kumar Rathore

Comment: @uvsmtid I just edited(may be formatting) this answer, I don't have any idea about it.