# saltstack testing: render as each host in turn

Tags: testing, automated-tests, salt-stack

We test saltstack scripts on vagrant boxes.  It sometimes happens that while testing changes for host A, we inadvertently cause a problem for host B.

I'd like to write a script that will at least render (call show_sls) as if the minion id were each host in turn.  This will remove at least one class of error.

I can think of some hacky ways of doing this, like changing the contents of /etc/salt/minion_id on each iteration.  But are there better ways?

I know far too little about how to test salt scripts well.  All suggestions most welcome.

### Pseudo-code example

To make this somewhat clearer, what I'd like might resemble this:

```
my_minions='a.example.com b.example.com c.example.com'
for minion_id in $my_minions; do
    sudo salt-call --local --minion="$minion_id" state.show_sls > /dev/null
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "$minion_id does not render"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [salt test interface](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/testing.html) to perform dry-run on all the minions by setting `test=True` option to the state along with [--retcode-passthrough](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2017.7/ref/cli/salt-call.html#cmdoption-salt-call--retcode-passthrough) flag which will `exit with the salt call retcode and not the salt binary retcode`, and check the retcode which is returned to check if the state will be rendered successfully, i.e,

```
salt-call state.sls teststate test=True --retcode-passthrough; echo $?
```

will print non-zero exit code if any state is unsuccessful.
To get list of minions you can loop through `/etc/salt/pki/master/minions`

(You can also set `test` to `true` by default in minion configuration file, then states will default to being executed in test mode.)

2nd approach could be setting [Failhard global option](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/failhard.html#global-failhard) in your master which will immediately stop all state execution and throw an error. You can run it in a same way as above, in this case execution will stop immediately after first failure, and you will have your retcode.

You might want to look at [kitchen-salt](https://saltstack.com/testing-your-salt-states-with-kitchen-salt/) as well,

> The goal of this kitchen-salt is to make it easy to test Salt States
>   or Formulas independently of a production environment. It allows for
>   doing quick checks of states and to make sure that upstream changes in
>   packages will not affect deployments. By using platforms, users can
>   run checks on their states against the environment they are running in
>   production as well as checking future releases of distributions before
>   doing major upgrades. It is also possible to test Salt States against
>   multiple versions of Salt to make sure there are no major regressions.

I would also like to mention that salt has no proper exit codes yet, and there are many [issues still open](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/18510) on this subject. If you want to check the output manually, you can use [this python script](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/b819961dbb683285329084952f24dab6f30d07c6/states/bootstrap/bootstrap.dir/modules/utils/check_salt_output.py) which is mentioned on [Track failure of command on a Salt minion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29960947/track-failure-of-command-on-a-salt-minion)